# Risk-neutral pricing

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

Consider the Black-Scholes market. Let $r$ the risk-free rate, $S$ the stock price process following the sde under the objective measure $P$
$$dS=\alpha S dt + \sigma S dW^P_t$$
where $\alpha >r> 0$.

We know that in order to avoid arbitrages a derivative with payoff $\phi$ must be priced by the formula
$$p(0,S)=\mathbb{E}^Q \left[e^{-rT}\phi(S_T) \big | S_0 \right]$$
under the risk-neutral meaure $Q$ which is obtained by a Girsanov transformation.

Under the risk-neutral measure I would pay $p(0,S)$ today to get an average return of $\mathbb{E}^Q \left[\phi(S_T) \big | S_0 \right]$ at time $T$ which corresponds to $e^{rT}$ of average return, so the risk-free return.

But this analysis doesn't make any sense from an investor point of view since we observe prices under the objective measure $P$. So from an investor point of view I will pay $p(0,S)$ in order to get an average return of $\mathbb{E}^P \left[\phi(S_T) \big | S_0 \right]$ at time $T$ which corresponds to average returns higher than the risk free return $e^{rT}$ in case for example of call options (since $\alpha >r$),  right?

In case of put options instead it should correspond to lower returns than the risk free return since I'm betting against the market, right?

Comment: If you sell (buy) the option for $p(0,S)$ and invest the proceeds (repay the loan) at the risk-free rate, then you receive (pay) $e^{rT}p(0,S)$ which, in theory, exactly offsets the cost (gain) of dynamically hedging with the underlying asset continuously and without friction through time. The "real" probability measure is irrelevant in assigning a fair value to the option.  If you buy or sell the option without hedging then the outcome is entirely random and determined by the "real" distribution whatever that may be.

Comment: Yes that is from a pricing point of view (from the bank which prices an option). But from an investor point of view, who doesn't care about arbitrage and stuff like that but just about his expected returns, it should be as I say right?

Comment: You suggest that the investor should actually be willing to pay a higher price $\mathbb{E}^P[\phi(S_T)]$ than the risk-neutral price $p(0,S_0)$ (say we're talking about a call option).  Why would they buy the option for a higher price when they could instead build a replicating portfolio for cheaper that gives them the same terminal payoff?  It's true that buying the option for $p(0,S_0)$ gives the investor a higher expected return than the risk free rate $r$, but so does just putting all their money in the stock - there's no contradiction there.  They get that higher return by taking on risk.

Comment: The second part of your last comment is what I meant, so we agree. It was a consideration on the fact that the investor has higher return on average then the risk free

Comment: Given the asymmetric payoff, the expected return of the option will depend on the drift $\alpha$ and the volatility $\sigma$ in a somewhat complicated way.  See [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/60797/8153) for the call option.